# Place TextView on top of an image view that has an elevation

Tags: android, android-layout

I have researched this extensively on stack overflow but found no answer that works for me. What I have is an `ImageView` that has an `elevation` (for a shadow effect) on top of that I want a `TextView`. I am going to repeat this for a number of elements in a `GridLayout`, hence `bringToFront()` does not look like a good option. Additionally, I don't want the `TextView` to have a shadow, hence the `translationZ` property of `xml` doesn't work either. Finally, I have tried using a `FrameLayout` for these two elements but I think because of the elevation property on the `Imageview`, the `TextView` still remains in the back. Following is my code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="2"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bids_number"
                android:background="@drawable/circulerimageblue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="10"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="1dp"
                android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:id="@+id/bids_icon"
                android:background="@drawable/circulerimageunselected"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_profile"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Get Bids"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is a picture of what I am trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: Can you share what is your expected output as image?

Comment: You need to remove  `app:cardElevation="8dp"` it will not effect your `TextView`

Comment: @sukhbir I removed that part and it still looks the same, thanks! Out of curiosity, is the shadow still there because of cardCornerRadius

Comment: `cardCornerRadius`  is used to make corner round

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **NOTE :** Please don't use negative margin

Try this USE **`CoordinatorLayout`**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_rowWeight="2"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp">


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/topPanel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bids_icon"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/kid" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Get Bids"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPink"
            android:text="10"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/bids_icon"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="right" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using a constraint layout or just the relative layout inside the card view, you don't need the linear layout, the relative layout should easily be able to handle what your're doing. As for the shadow trying this

Create a file shadow_rect.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="1dp"  android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Then apply it to the image background, you can ofcourse tinker with the above drawable to get the required shadow type.

That should handle the illusion of elevation by giving it a shadow so you don't need `elevation` anymore as that's an API 21+ property.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code**

> Change your `name` and `icon` and `color`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns`enter code here`:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/dp_10"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dp_10"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp_10"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/dp_10"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp_1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_65"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/circulerimageunselected"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/dp_2"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close"
                    android:padding="@dimen/dp_10"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_65" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_40"
                android:text="10"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp_15"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/tile_bg"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:textSize="@dimen/dp_20"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_20"
            android:text="Get Birds"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```